# Use Case Email Notification

Tags: oop, use-case, ooad

I have a question in modelling Use Case.
1) If a actor(or user) registers an account in a System and if the System sends Successful Registration Email notification to the actor. Should it be considered as separate use case for email notification or is it part of 'Register Account' Use case?

2) If there is a scenario where user account is terminated by another user who is system administrator. The terminated user needs to be notified that his account is terminated by email. In this case, Should the email notification be a separate use case or an "include" use case with "Terminate Account" use case?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system sends the emails automatically and the user has to do nothing but the main use case, they are not separate use cases. They are merely a reaction of your system to a given use case. It is then a post-condition of said use case that the email has been sent out.

Answer (score 0):

I think email sending is not different use case. But when you are implementing this, you are should seperate responsibility of register account to account class and email sending behaviour should be part of EmailSender classs.

Email notification and register or terminate account are different behavior of system. Every class should have single responsibility and including email sending as part of account class doesn't make any sense.